# Spring Security - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must provide a configuration attribute

Tags: grails, spring-security

I was unable to run my grails project suddenly and I'm getting this error. Please see full stacktrace below. How do I solve this error?

```
boot.SpringApplication              Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must provide a configuration attribute
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:181)
    at org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig.<init>(SecurityConfig.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor78.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ReflectionUtils.buildConfigAttributes(ReflectionUtils.groovy:163)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ReflectionUtils.buildConfigAttributes(ReflectionUtils.groovy)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.InterceptedUrl.<init>(InterceptedUrl.groovy:40)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findActionRoles(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:470)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:427)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findControllerAnnotations(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:384)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.initialize(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:225)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition$initialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.initializeFromAnnotations(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:770)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:651)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:523)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:251)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at ifs.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of your @Secured annotations has no roles or expressions, e.g.`@Secured('')`. Search through your controllers and make sure that all of the annotations have correct values.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Can't believe I missed that. Could you point out which line(s) in the stacktrace that hints about the error?

Comment: `AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.findAnnotations` indicates you're using  annotations, and the `InterceptedUrl` constructor call in `findActionRoles()` calls `ReflectionUtils.buildConfigAttributes()` with the token(s) obtained from the annotations. That calls `new SecurityConfig(token)` which throws the exception because the token is a blank string.